# Trait bound on generic trait

Tags: generics, traits, rust

I want to know how to create a generic function bound to a generic trait.

In this example I have chosen `BitXor`. The declaration of `std::ops::BitXor` is `BitXor<RHS, Result>`.

So if we have our function:

```
fn e<T: BitXor>(m:T, k:T) -> T {
    m ^ k
}
```

The compiler will complain:

```
error: Wrong number of type arguments: expected 2 but found 0.
```

So I tried:

```
fn e<T: BitXor<U, V>, U, V>(m:T, k:T) -> T {
    m ^ k
}
```

But get the rather confusing error:

```
Mismatched types: expected `U` but found `T` (expected type parameter but found type parameter).
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the full definition of the BitXor trait:

```
#[lang="bitxor"]
pub trait BitXor<RHS, Result> {
    fn bitxor(&self, rhs: &RHS) -> Result;
}
```

Notice how the `rhs` operand is of type `&RHS`. In your case, `RHS` is `U` (because you have `BitXor<U, V>`), yet `k`, which you pass as `rhs` through the `^` operator, is of type `T`. Likewise, the result is of type `Result`, which in your case is `V`, yet your function returns `T`.

There are two possible signatures, depending on your use case:

```
fn e<T: BitXor<U, V>, U, V>(m: T, k: U) -> V {
    m ^ k
}
```

In this one, we use more type parameters to get maximum genericity.

```
fn e<T: BitXor<T, T>>(m: T, k: T) -> T {
    m ^ k
}
```

In this one, we sacrifice genericity to restrict all values to be of the same type.